# Strange character added while compilation, leads to an error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

When compiling a project with Visual Studio Express 2013, I get this error

> ....\WDL\IPlug\IPlugVST3.cpp(199): error C2065: 'Lp' : undeclared identifier [D:\wdl-ol\IPlugExamples\MyFirstPlugin\MyFirstPlugin-vst3.vcxproj]

The strange thing is that the file `IPlugVST3.cpp` doesn't contain `Lp` but only `p`:

```
 switch (p->Type())
  {
    case IParam::kTypeDouble:
    case IParam::kTypeInt:
    {
      Parameter* param = new RangeParameter( STR16(p->GetNameForHost()), // <---- this line
                                             i,
                                             STR16(p->GetLabelForHost()),
                                             p->GetMin(),
                                             p->GetMax(),
                                             p->GetDefault(),
                                             0, // continuous
                                             flags,
                                             unitID);

      param->setPrecision (p->GetPrecision());
      parameters.addParameter(param);
```

**Why does the C++ compiler understands it a `Lp` instead of `p` ?**

*Note: I checked if there are no hidden unicode characters (does this exist?) but no...*

Comment: Is STR16 a macro? Can you provide the code for it?

Comment: I expect `STR16` is macro which expects a string literal as an argument, e.g. `#define STR16(s) L##s` or some such.

Comment: @PaulR True! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You need to present your [MCVE] before this question is answered.

Comment: @Basj: sure - comment now converted to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STR16` is most likely a macro which expects a string literal as an argument, e.g.

```
#define STR16(s) L##s
```

or something similar. It you pass a variable instead of a string literal then you will get something like the problem you are observing.